# iOS 5 Segue from uitableviewcell to another uitableview to detail view (storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uistoryboard

a tab based contains two items. the first one is just a view.
the second item points to uinavigatiocontroller, and it points to uiviewtablecontroler. tapping on the cell segues to the next uitableview. till this point everthing is working. now i wannt to segue from the second uitable to a detail view. i cant get it work. i put another navigation controller before the second one, but segueing to navigation controller wont work?! or am i missing something?

tab based navigation:
item 1: view controller (working)
item 2: navigation controller -> uitableview -> uitableview -> detail view
so i cant get it to segue from second uitableview to detail view.

both tables are populated with nsarray.
any idea?  can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put in a second navigation controller.  There should just be one navigation controller per tab.  The navigation controller should have a "root view controller" connection to the first table view controller.  The first table view controller should have a Push segue to the second table view controller.  The second table view controller should have a Push segue to the detail view controller.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i found out that i mistyped the identifier in code. so it works now.

Comment: hello @robmayoff, I have a question,please. is it possible for a push segue to happen just inside a subview? I have an ipad app, I have a small subview in the lower left corner. Is it possible to just do the push segue there? I'm trying it now, but when I do a segue, it pushes to the entire full screen... would you have any idea on how to do that? I also cannot find questions similar to this in stack overflow, probably because I don't have the right words...